# What genes are the muscles, nerves, bones and blood?

Tags: genetics

I have a question about genes. The question is that bones, muscles, nerves and blood are each made on which genes. Father or mother genes? Does the person take any of the characteristics of the mother or father? Thank you.

Comment: The question is very unclear. I don't know either what you mean by mother and father gene. You are maybe referring to maternally vs paternally inherited chromosomes. Then, the answer would be both. You should just have a look to a intro to genetics.

Answer (score 1):

**Most genes case:**
Let's state back what a gene is: it is a portion of the genome, numerous versions of a gene exists (called alleles). But one individual can only have two alleles in the same time (one from his mother and one from his father). So gene coding for nerve, muscles are present in both your mom and dad, and you will inherit of half of their allele (1 from each). There it is 50/50!

**The exception**
You maybe know women and men have a slight difference in genome: the sexual chromosome, men have XY and women XX. So the only case I could see a gene only inherited by your father would be that this particular gene is present on the Y chromosome.